# What built-in types does Jackson 2.6 support?

Tags: jackson

What built-in types does Jackson support?  For example, it obviously supports `String`.  The tutorials suggest that it can handle collections like `List` transparently.  I saw a blog post that says it can handle `URI` and `URL`.  I'm looking for a complete list of types that it can handle automagically as of version 2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a full list. It might be easier to claim that most of JDK, as of Java 6, is directly supported; certainly most (if not all) of `java.util` and `java.lang`, much of `java.util.concurrent`, and then combinations thereof via `List`/`Map`/arrays.
It might be a good idea to suggest creation of a list of supported types on Jackson user or dev lists -- it sounds like a useful thing.

Types introduced in later JDK versions are added via separate modules like `jackson-datatype-jdk7`, `jackson-datatype-jdk8`.